# Jquery .submit wont intercept form submission

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have php code that echos a form that was inserted into my html by another jquery code. This all works fine.  I am trying to submit this form with ajax.

```
echo '<form id="comment_form" action="commentvalidation.php?PhotoID='.$_GET['PhotoID'].'" method="POST">';
echo '<label>Comment: </label>';
echo '<textarea id="description" name="CommentDesc" cols="25" rows="2"></textarea>';
echo '<input class="button" id="comment_btn" type="submit" name="Comment" value="Comment" >';
echo '</form>';
```

The form works fine when submitted traditionally. The problem is I cant get it to be be submitted with ajax. The .submit just wont prevent the default action.

```
<script>
$(function(){

        $('#comment_form').submit(function() {
          alert("we are in");

                    $.post($('#comment_form').attr('action'), $('#comment_form').serialize(), function(data){
                        $('#comment_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    });
            //Important. Stop the normal POST
            return false;
        });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Search for `preventDefault`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be from the fact that `form that was inserted into my html by another jquery code`. From what I understood from this, the form was dynamically created after the page was loaded.

In that case when the `submit` handler registration code was executed the element was not existing in the dom structure - means the handler was never registered to the form.

Try using a delegated event handler to solve this

```
$(function(){

        $(document).on('submit', '#comment_form', function() {
          alert("we are in");

                    $.post($('#comment_form').attr('action'), $('#comment_form').serialize(), function(data){
                        $('#comment_form').html("<div id='message'></div>");
                    });
            //Important. Stop the normal POST
            return false;
        });
});
```

Demo: [Problem](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YNV2s/2/)
Demo: [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/YNV2s/)

Comment: Strangely, your *Problem* example works fine. Maybe a weird JSFiddle thing. Also, nice answer, [looks familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17872740/283366)

Answer (score 1):

You're probably binding the *submit* event handler before the form is in your page. Use event delegation instead of direct binding, for example

```
$(document.body).on('submit', '#comment_form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('We are in');

    // and the rest, no need for return false
});
```

As an addendum, try not to echo out great chunks of HTML from PHP. It's much more readable and you're less likely to run into problems with quotes and concatenation if you just switch to the PHP context when required, eg

```
// break out of the PHP context
?>
<form id="comment_form" action="commentvalidation.php?PhotoID=<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['PhotoID']) ?>" method="POST">
<label>Comment: </label>
<textarea id="description" name="CommentDesc" cols="25" rows="2"></textarea>
<input class="button" id="comment_btn" type="submit" name="Comment" value="Comment" >
</form>
<?php
// and back to PHP
```

Comment: That was the issue. The only reason I didnt break out of php context is that the action of the form had a $_GET[].

Comment: @paulfj As does my example above. See the part with `<?= htmlspecialchars($_GET['PhotoID']) ?>`?

Comment: Ohhh didnt notice that. Didn't know i could do that. Thank you.